# add / remove class in jquery window scroll function not working - blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ask for help, why my script is not working,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
}
else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
}
});
```

I tried to replace `$(window).scroll(function() {` with `$(document).ready(function() {` ,still does not work

for more details, you can open my page in [versbubble.blogspot.com](http://versbubble.blogspot.com)

Comment: infinite loading occuring in  versbubble.blogspot.com

Comment: If you check the console when on your site you'll see the problem, you haven't included jQuery: `bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`. Your code works fine when you include jQuery in the page: https://jsfiddle.net/w4we06cp/.

Comment: please, reload page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do I have to remove the bootstrap script ?

Comment: @user2621248 `jQuery` should come first in order.

Comment: As @Muhammad said, you need to include jQuery *before* bootstrap. Also note that using Google drive as a CDN is not a great idea.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Is it wrong to put the code jquery, before the </ body> or after <head> ?

Comment: No, either is fine. The important thing is that any dependencies are included first in the page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, explanation,
What should I do, I have to move my script host?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $('header').addClass("sticky");
        }
        else {
            $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am not too late, I had the same issue lately so I did something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function() {    
            if ($(window).offset().top  > 50){  
                $('header').addClass("sticky");
            }

            if ($(window).scrollTop() < 50){  
                $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            }

        });
    });
```